# Get nested elements in hierarchical manner C# linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have list of objects which is map as Parent- child relationship.
so parent have many children, grand children and great grandchildren and so on.
I have structured table as below

```
UserId UserNme 
1      Jack    
2      William   
3      asha      
4      winston

ParentId ChildId
2          3
3          4
```

**So I want to list the users in following hierarchical manner:**

->User not as child (Parent/Non-parent)
----> Child Users
-------->Grand child users   
-----------> Great Grand child users

**I have tried below code, but not completed it:**

```
 public List<MarketingUserDto> GetChildAgents(List<MarketingUserDto> agents,List<MarketingUserDto> resultAgents)
    {

        if (agents.Count == 0)
        {                
            var parentagents = _userRegistrationRepository.GetMany(x => ((x.IsParentAgent ?? false) == true && x.UserTypeId == (short)Enums.UserTypes.Agent) || (x.UserTypeId == (short)Enums.UserTypes.Super_Manager && (x.IsParentAgent ?? false) == false));
            this.GetChildAgents(Mapper.Map<List<UserRegistration>, List<MarketingUserDto>>(parentagents.ToList()), resultAgents);
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var agent in agents)
            {
                var childagents = _agentMappingRepository.GetMany(x => x.ParentId == agent.UserId, y => y.UserRegistration);

            }
        }
        return resultAgents;
    }
```

Could you please provide any suggestion how to achieve this?

Comment: So you want it flattened in a singular list?

Comment: Can you not do it closer to the data source?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to reinvent the flattening wheel, take a look at MoreLinq's `Flatten()` [extension method](https://github.com/morelinq/MoreLINQ/blob/master/MoreLinq/Flatten.cs).

If you grab the [NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq), you get that and a lot more useful LINQ extensions.